# Cross-browser addevent function javascript

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, addeventlistener

I'm trying to create a function that adds an event to each button in a class. I have all of the buttons in an array and wanted to use [Dustin Diaz's addevent() cross browser solution](http://dustindiaz.com/rock-solid-addevent), but am unsure how to implement it. I'm used to using frameworks for this sort of thing, but have to use pure JS for this one.
Any pointers or advice on how to use Dustin's solution would be appreciated.

Ok so after taking @Pointy 's advice, I wrote this that checks for `addEventListener` and if not uses `attachEvent` This however is not calling testFunction(). What am I doing wrong here?

```
function addEvents()
{
  var buttonArray=document.getElementsByClassName('mainButton');

  for(i=0; i < buttonArray.length; i++)
  {
    if (i.addEventListener) {
      i.addEventListener("click", testFunction);
    } 
    else if (i.attachEvent) {
      i.attachEvent("onclick", testFunction);
    }

    function testFunction() {
      alert("Test");
    } 
  }

  // Attach an event to each button that when clicked on will display an alert that say 'Button X clicked' where X = the button ID
}
```

Comment: That code is **antique**.

Comment: I agree- it is old. I'm also open to other solutions that don't use frameworks if anyone knows of any.

Comment: @exeleon You should be able to use jquery's [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) function or [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.

Comment: @Didericis he said he can't use a framework like jQuery.

Comment: I think all you need to do is check for `addEventListener` and fall back to `attachEvent` for older versions of IE. I would suggest not bothering with `onfoo` properties at all.

Comment: @Pointy Jquery isn't really a framework. I assumed he was talking about something like Angularjs.

Comment: @Didericis thats my fault, jquery is technically a library and though, tempting to use I can't in this particular case. I would have to use what pointy suggested and check for addEventListener and if not, fall back.

Comment: @Pointy I updated my post with some code

Comment: You are trying to add an event to a number. The call should be "buttonArray[i].addEventListener"...

Comment: @Andreas Why not make your comment an answer...

Comment: @Andreas yea, so I could click the check mark because that worked! I thank the stack overflow community once again for pointing out how stupid I  can be at times. I thought it looked a little funky, but its been so long since I played with JS I didn't even realize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add an event to a number. You should replace "i" with "buttonArray[i]" and add an else-case (defensive coding).

```
function addEvents() {
    var buttonArray = document.getElementsByClassName('mainButton');
    for(i = 0; i < buttonArray.length; i++) {    
        if (buttonArray[i].addEventListener) {
            buttonArray[i].addEventListener("click", testFunction);
        } else if (buttonArray[i].attachEvent) {
            buttonArray[i].attachEvent("onclick", testFunction);
        } else {
            throw new Error("This should be unreachable");
        }
    }

    function testFunction() {
        alert("Test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I had one last question The code works with chrome and IE but does not work with firefox. Nothing comes up in firebug, its just unresponsive

Comment: Is it possible that you checked "Don't allow this website to show messages" in an alert-box? Try console.log or changing some color on the page instead of showing the alert.

Comment: I got it straightened out, I changed it to `}else{ if (..) }` rather than `}else if {` and something started working. I appreciate all of your feed back!

Comment: You should really check and understand, what is going on there. The two statements are totally equivalent if used correctly. Just pull up some debugger and check what is going wrong there.

Comment: Thats what I thought and you're most definitely right. I may have done something else than that affected it and caused it to work in Firefox that I'm just not realizing.